# Is there a difference between these two ways of moving a branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I was following the interactive [LearnGitBranching](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/) tutorial and came across two ways of moving around a branch. I want to be sure that I am not missing anything.

Is there a difference between:

```
 git branch -f master master^
```

and, supposing `HEAD` points to `master`,

```
git reset HEAD^
```

And, if they do the same thing, why have the `reset` command at all? Would it mean it's simply a shorthand for `git branch -f`?

Thank you kindly!

Comment: I'm not sure if those two behave exactly the same. But the `reset` command has `--soft`, `--mixed`, and `--hard` options. As well as others which give it a bit more flexibility than `branch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As genisage noted in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478633/is-there-a-difference-between-these-two-ways-of-moving-a-branch#comment39763724_25478633), `git reset` has multiple modes.

Ignoring all of the modes and what they do, the answer to the first question is: if `HEAD` refers to `master` and you move `master` to another commit with `git branch`, then yes, this achieves the same thing as indirectly moving `master` with `git reset`.  But:

1. We can't simply ignore the options to `reset`.
2. We also started the answer with "if `HEAD` refers to `master`".  What if it doesn't?

In particular, for point #1, the default mode for `git reset` is `--mixed`.  The `reset` command can, and in this case does, do more than just move the branch-tip.  It can also update git's index (aka "staging area").

You can—and in fact, probably should—think of git's index / staging area as "what git is ready to commit the next time you run `git commit`".  When you `git add` a file to make git pick up changes for the next commit, git reads the current work-tree version of that file, then writes that<sup>1</sup> into the index.

What `git reset` does (or can do, and does with `--mixed`) is *undo* this kind of index-modification, by changing the index contents to match the commit you reset-to.  That is, `git reset --mixed HEAD^` not only backs the branch up one commit, but *also* resets all the index contents to the backed-up-by-one commit.  The `git branch` command does not touch the index.

You *can* make `git reset` not touch the index, by using the `--soft` option.  In this case, it really does do the same thing as your `git branch -f`—although, as noted in point #2, this only works if `HEAD` refers to `master`.  If you want to do a soft reset without using `git reset`, your first step is to find out what branch, if any, `HEAD` points to.  Only then can you update the branch (and then only if you're not in "detached HEAD" mode).

For completeness, it's worth noting here that `git reset --hard` does even more than `git reset --mixed`: it not only updates the branch-tip and resets the index, it also "resets" your work tree, making it look like the new target commit.

It's also worth adding that several common uses of `git reset` deliberately only make use of some of its actions:

- `git reset --soft HEAD^` backs you up one commit, without changing the index or work-tree, so that a new `git commit` provides a new branch-tip with the same contents as the commit you just backed-up-over.  This lets you change the commit message.<sup>2</sup>  This is exactly the same as `git commit --amend`, except that the latter is actually easier; so this usage is not common any more (it was how one did this before `git commit` *had* the `--amend` option).
- `git reset --mixed -- <path>` "moves" you to your current commit—that is, it rewrites the current branch to point to where it already points, which is a no-op—but resets the index, without altering the work-tree.  This lets you "undo" a `git add` or `git rm --cached`.<sup>3</sup>  Usually it's just spelled `git reset <path>`, since `--mixed` is the default.
- `git reset --hard` or `git reset --hard <path>` again "moves" you not at all, but resets the index and restores the work-tree version.

The `reset` command has several extra options (`--merge` and `--keep`; and also `-p`) that don't quite fit this pattern.  I'm just going to ignore them here, though, to keep this answer from getting way too long.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, git writes the file (or "blob") to the *repository*, rather than to the index.  In the process of writing the blob, git also calculates the resulting SHA-1: the "true name" of the object.  (All repository objects are found by their "true name" SHA-1s.  The repository acts as a simple key-value store, with the key being the SHA-1, and the value being the object: the file aka "blob", or tree, or commit, or annotated-tag-object.)  The SHA-1 goes into the index, along with the file's name and execute-permission bit.  The index is later turned into one or more git "tree" objects at commit time, as needed; those tree objects contain the various file names, modse/execute-permissions, and SHA-1s.

<sup>2</sup>More precisely, you make a new, different commit with the corrected message.  This is also what `git commit --amend` does.  The old (pre-amendment) commit is still in the repository, with its same SHA-1; the new commit, with its different message and different time-stamp, has a different SHA-1, even though it starts from the same index, and hence has the same tree attached.

<sup>3</sup>A regular (not `--cached`) `git rm` has removed the file from the work-tree, so `git reset --mixed` won't do.  `git reset --hard <path>` will do, or you can `git checkout HEAD -- <path>` to get the file back.  The latter "writes through" the index, so again these wind up being pretty much redundant command-wise, like `git reset --soft` vs `git branch -f`.

Comment: You write: *This is exactly the same as `git commit --amend`*. But `git reset --soft HEAD^` is still useful if you want to pretend that that last commit never happened, instead of amending it (i.e. replacing it with a new one).

Comment: @Jubobs: yes, that was a list of "common tasks for which `git reset` is used" rather than a comprehensive list of "all possible uses" :-)  You can also "git reset --soft <other-point>".  [VonC](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) put it something like: if you're happy with the tree, but not the series of commits used to arrive at it, `git reset --soft` is often the answer.

Comment: I like that `:)` Which post did VonC write that in?

Comment: About your 3rd footnote... There is one important distinction between `git checkout HEAD --` and `git reset --mixed --`: the former will let you unstage *any* changes (addition, edit, move/rename, deletion), whereas the latter won't allow you to unstage a move.

Comment: @Jubobs: `git mv` is shorthand, as it were, for `git rm` and `git add` (except that they're done simultaneously and atomically by the one `mv` operation).  Which is just another way of saying that you're right, really. :-)