# What are typical use cases of git-reset's --merge and --keep flags?

Tags: git, git-reset

In a [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25479271/2541573) in which he details the typical use cases of `git-reset`'s three most commonly used options (`--hard`, `--mixed`, and `--soft`), [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) mentions  in passing that `git-reset` also offers two relatively esoteric flags, called `--merge` and `--keep`. The [`git-reset` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) describes those two flags as follows:

> ```
> --merge
>            
>    Resets the index and updates the files in the working tree
>    that are different between <commit> and HEAD, but keeps
>    those which are different between the index and working tree
>    (i.e. which have changes which have not been added). If a
>    file that is different between <commit> and the index has
>    unstaged changes, reset is aborted.
>
>    In other words, --merge does something like a git read-tree
>    -u -m <commit>, but carries forward unmerged index entries.
>
> --keep
>     Resets index entries and updates files in the working tree
>     that are different between <commit> and HEAD. If a file that
>     is different between <commit> and HEAD has local changes,
>     reset is aborted.
> ```

I perfectly understand when to use `--hard`, `--mixed`, or `--soft`, but I only learned that `--merge` and `--keep` existed while reading torek's answer, and I can't think of practical use cases of those two flags... In what situations do you typically use those two flags?

I'm mainly looking for a plain-English explanation. Take the following passage of [this answer by VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203535/practical-uses-of-git-reset-soft/5203843#5203843), which spells out a typical use case for `git reset --soft`, as a model:

> [...] each time:
>
> - you are satisfied with what you end up with (in term of working tree and index)
> - you are not satisfied with all the commits that took you to get there:
>
> `git reset --soft` is the answer.

However, I'm not averse to a little experiment with those flags, similar in spirit to the silly shopping-list example I posted in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25535829/2541573).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Frankly I'm not really sure about this; I've never even used the `--merge` and `--keep` modes myself.  However, the release notes indicate that `git reset --merge` was added in git version 1.6.2, with the following note:

- `git reset --merge` is a new mode that works similar to the way
  `git checkout` switches branches, taking the local changes while
  switching to another commit.

and `--keep` was added in 1.7.1:

- `git reset` learned `--keep` option that lets you discard commits
  near the tip while preserving your local changes in a way similar
  to how `git checkout branch` does.

Then, in 1.7.9:

- `git checkout -B <current branch> <elsewhere>` is a more intuitive
  way to spell `git reset --keep <elsewhere>`.

which tells us that the idea behind `--keep` is, you have started work on some branch, and then you realize: oh, this branch should fork off from some other point (probably the tip of some other branch).  For instance you might:

```
$ git checkout devel
$ git checkout -b fix-bug-1234
```

and then do some work to fix bug 1234 for the next release; but then someone says: "hey, we need bug 1234 fixed for the old release version!"  So now you want `fix-bug-1234` to branch off from `release` instead of `devel`.  Meanwhile you haven't committed anything yet.  So you:

```
$ git checkout -B fix-bug-1234 release
```

to move it to "coming off release" instead of "coming off devel".  Which works in 1.7.9 or later, but in 1.7.1 through 1.7.8 you have to spell it `git reset --keep`.

That might explain `--keep` but `--merge` is still a bit of a mystery.

Comment: In your example, if you're editing `buggy-file.c` when you switch from `git reset --keep fix-bug-1234`, the reset will fail if `buggy-file.c` is different in branch `devel` and branch `fix-buf-1234`.  Hence, `--merge`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: but in that case, per the description of `--merge`: `buggy-file.c` *is* different between the index and `<commit>` (it's different in `devel` than `release`) *and* it has unstaged changes (we've modified the work tree), so therefore `git reset --merge` will abort the reset too.  I have the feeling something is off in the man-page description.  The source code indicates that `--merge` is allowed in the middle of a conflicted merge, while `--soft` and `--keep` are not.

Comment: @torek Thanks for that. Those flags remain quite exotic to me, though. If I ever feel the need to use them, I might come back here and post my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that at a first look those flags seem to be exotic. It took me hours to understand them, however the difference is pretty clear: `--keep` unstages the index while `--merge` completely discards the index.

Going back to a typical use cases: Imagine that you have a configuration file specific to your local environement, e.g., containing credentials to your local database. When you are going to do a "hard" reset, then for sure you don't want to loose your local changes. In that case

```
git reset --keep <commit>
```

perfectly does the job. This shows that more often you want to use `--keep` flag instead of `--hard` flag.

The flag `--merge` is a bit more aggressive than `--keep` since it completely discardes the index (notice that in this case you can lose your work in opposite to `--keep`), but in my opinion the practical use cases for both of them are the same.

Originally, `git reset --merge` was introduced to abort a merge, but now `git merge --abort` is prefered (the first option was introduced in `1.6.2` version while the second one in `1.7.4`).

Comment: >> --keep unstages the index
There is no such thing as unstaging the index.
 
From documentation:
 --keep
Resets index entries...

Answer (score 1):

From https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

> reset --keep is meant to be used when removing some of the last
> commits in the current branch while keeping changes in the working
> tree. If there could be conflicts between the changes in the commit we
> want to remove and the changes in the working tree we want to keep,
> the reset is disallowed. That’s why it is disallowed if there are both
> changes between the working tree and HEAD, and between HEAD and the
> target. To be safe, it is also disallowed when there are unmerged
> entries.

I can think about scenario where there are some local commits: Commit0, Commit1, Commit2, ..., CommitX, CommitY, ..., CommitN

and I want to discard changes in Commit1..CommitX, but preserve changes in CommitY..CommitN

In order to do this I could use `git reset --soft CommitX`, and then `git reset --keep Commit0`

I guess without --keep, someone would need to use stash in order to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

If you pulled from a branch, after that you see, oh! there are multiple conflicts. Then suddenly you remember you had pulled from the wrong branch then it will help to revert it.

```
git reset --merge HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a very terse answer. Could you describe what that command does and why it's useful?